# Reading input from a file

Tags: c++

list.txt

```
first 10
second third 20
fourth fifth 30
.
.
.
```

What's the conventional way to read the first line separately from the others, such that I can use "first","second", ... and 10, 20, ... as their respective types elsewhere in the program?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything.  Specifically, I want to read the first line, do something with "first" and 10, then read the rest of the lines with the ability to use "second","third", 20, and the rest of the strings/ints in the file.

Comment: You want to read in a string (`first`) and an int (`10`), is that it?

Comment: so you can read first line separately and then others in loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're thinking of?

```
ifstream fin("list.txt");

string str1, str2;
int n;

fin >> str1 >> n; // first 10

// do something with "first" and 10

while(fin >> str1 >> str2 >> n)
{
  // do something with str1, str2 and n
}
```

Comment: Can I just say cout << str1 << n;?

Comment: @BobJohn, in the "do something" part? Sure. Or you could do `cout << str1 << " " << n << endl;`.

Comment: When I try to implement this exactly as you have it it outputs a large number to the terminal that isn't related to "first" or 10.

Comment: That's odd; I get "first 10". You're sure about `list.txt`, that it's a plain text file, e.g. you can do `head -n 1 list.txt` and get "first 10"?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct header { 
    std::string name;
    int number;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, header &h) { 
    return is >> h.name >> h.number;
}

struct line { 
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
    int number;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &data) { 
    returns is >> data.first >> data.second >> data.number;
}

int main() { 
    header h;
    std::ifstream data("list.txt");

   // read first line:
   data >> h;
   // now h.name and h.number are the string and number from the first line

   // read the rest of the lines:
   std::vector<line> lines((std::istream_iterator<line>(data),
                            std::istream_iterator<line>());

   // now lines[i].first, lines[i].second and lines[i].number
   // are the first string, second string, and number
   // from the i-th line of three-field data from the file.

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks cool! But isn't it too complicated? I mean when to understand the logic of simple function you have to look at several methods or classes it's not good. Just my opinion

Comment: @nogard: At least in my experience, the tendency is for the code overall to end up simpler and easier to understand. Yes, it can (and all too often does) result in longer code than I'd like -- but the code to read (or write) a particular structure is typically so trivial you can almost ignore it, but still keeps the rest of the code really simple too. The ability to use standard algorithms for I/O usually outweighs the code for the `operator<<` and `operator>>`.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Still I don't see need to build 'framework' when we even don't know what structure OP needs. He might simply need to fill map<string, int>. Another point is that if you have 3 lines of code instead of 30, it means your code is easier to maintain and understand.